# wordpress contact form7 and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, safari

I have problem with safari 5.1 (and other version) in my wordperss contact form. Contact Form 7 use a preventDefault and I think it may be problem.

Code view like this:

```
    var $form = $( this );


    $form.submit( function( event ) {
        if ( typeof window.FormData !== 'function' ) {
            return;
        }

        wpcf7.submit( $form );


        event.preventDefault();
    } );
```

I try to add a return false; after a preventDefault but it's not help. Website still send form "normally", not via ajax. If you have a safari you can see a error on this:
[PreviewPage](http://pomyslownia.twsoft.pl/) (Please click "Umów się na spotkanie" button to open form).

Comment: try to move the event.preventDefault(); to the start of your function!?

Comment: It not help , If you can please visit on https://caniuse.com/#search=preventDefault and see safari 5 not compability but my client use that version...

Comment: can you help me ?